# Question on a justification of the Ratio Test

Tags: real-analysis

Given a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ with $a_n\neq 0$, the Ratio Test states that if $(a_n)$ satisfies

$$\lim\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=r<1,$$

then the series converges absolutely. 
I've shown

- Let $r'$ satisfy $r<r'<1$. Explain why there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_{n+1}| \leq |a_n|r'$.
- Why does $|a_N| \sum(r')^n$ converge?

but am unsure of how to justify that $\sum |a_n|$ converges, and conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You actually wrote that, looked at it, and decided your math typesetting looked just fine for a question here?

Comment: I apologize, I was doing this from my phone and just had the chance to look at it through my computer.

Comment: It's easy to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(r')^{n}=\frac{(r')^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$, since $|r'|<1$, so $|a_N| \sum (r')^{n}$ converges and implies that $\sum |a_n|$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test states, that if

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < 1$$

then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. So if that holds we have to be able to find a $\gamma < 1$ and an integer $N$ such that for $n \geq N$

$$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < \gamma$$

holds (remember the definition of $\limsup$). Thus

\begin{align*}
\left| a_{N+1} \right| &< \gamma \left| a_{N} \right| \\
\left| a_{N+2} \right| &< \gamma \left| a_{N+1} \right| < \gamma^2 \left| a_{N} \right| \\
\vdots \\
\left| a_{N+p} \right| &< \gamma^p \left| a_{N} \right|
\end{align*}

which is equivalent to

$$\left| a_{n} \right| < \left| a_{N} \right| \gamma^{-N} \gamma^n \iff \left| \frac{a_{n}}{a_N} \right| \gamma^N < \gamma^n \implies \frac{\gamma^N}{\left| a_N \right|} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| a_{n} \right|  < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n$$

which implies (absolute) convergence since $\gamma^n < 1$ (geometric series).

To prove/understand the implication

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| a_{n} \right| \quad \text{converges} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \quad \text{converges}$$

remember that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \leq \left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| a_{n} \right|$$

Comment: Ah, one of the steps I was trying was to multiply $r'$ $n$ times to arrive at the inequality, but I see what I was missing.